# Auto assign public IPs to my instance created by an austo-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, scaling

I have an Auto-Scaling group (min. 1 instance and max. 5) with my website running there.
This first instance public IP is pointing to my domain "example.com"
But when the auto-scaling group create another instance (due the load incrementation) with another public IP, if I try to access to the new instance, this IP doesn't resolve to my domain "example.com" till I include this new public IP into my host filename or into my dns manager (godaddy).

How could I solve this and automatise this process?

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
KV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place an AWS load balancer in front of your EC2 instances. Attach the auto-scaling group to the load balancer so that instances are automatically added to the load balancer's pool when they are created, and automatically removed from the pool when they are terminated. Point your domain name to the load balancer instead of individual instances.

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your response.
Currrently, I have an ELB already set. But how can I point my domain name to the ELB? The ELB has no public IP, only public dns address

Kind Regards

Comment: If you are trying to host a subdomain then you just need to create a CNAME record and not worry about IP addresses at all. If you are trying to host a root domain, the commonly used method is to host your DNS with Route53 and create an `ALIAS` record that points to the load balancer. Some other DNS hosts can point a root domain to a load balancer's DNS name like CloudFlare's CNAME Flattening feature.